# List searching that does not terminate

Tags: prolog

This time I really cannot understand the error: i wrote this code to get the list element at a certain position:

```
take_pos([], _, _) :- fail;
take_pos([H|T], 1, H).
take_pos([H|T], Pos, X) :- Pos2 is Pos - 1, take_pos(T, Pos2, X).
```

It never terminates; tracing it I can see that it never match the second statement. Also if i query `take_pos([1,2,3], 1, 1).` it match the last one.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you put a semicolon instead of a dot after `fail`.

Also consider rewriting the second rule to avoid introducing a singleton:

```
take_pos([], _, _) :- fail.
take_pos([H|_], 1, H).
take_pos([H|T], Pos, X) :- Pos2 is Pos - 1, take_pos(T, Pos2, X).
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the first clause has a `;` where I think you meant `.`.
Anyway, that first clause if corrected does nothing so it should be removed entirely:

```
take_pos([H|T], 1, H).
take_pos([H|T], Pos, X) :- Pos2 is Pos - 1, take_pos(T, Pos2, X).
```